# A Question about rationality , irrationality or Transcendence of definite integral

Tags: analysis, reference-request, definite-integrals, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

( this is my first question on the site so please forgive any possible mistake )

Consider integral of the form :

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$$

> > Can we have a set of conditions of $f(x)$ such that we can assure the value is rational or irrational( transcendental ) ?
>
> Is/are there such type of standard result in literature ?

Comment: No, there isn't. Would be too nice to be true.

Comment: I mean, barring trivial stuff like specifying what the limiting values of an antiderivative of $f$ are at 0 and $\infty$...

Comment: Or $f$ being a rational function whose poles are all Gaussian rationals and have residue $0$.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments ,Is there any special case for a general class of functions ?